# Formatação errada ao abrir um PDF gerado por latex

Tags: java, pdf, encode

Em meu programa preciso abrir um arquivo PDF e pegar o texto que contem nele. Porém ao abrir o PDF, o texto vem mal formatado. Por exemplo:
**Agradec ¸o a ` minha fam´ ?lia por nao ? medir esforc ¸os**
Quando o certo seria:
**Agradeço à minha família por não medir esforçoes**

Isso só ocorre quando o PDF e gerado por latex. Quando é gerado pelo word, o texto está normal.
O código que estou utilizando para abrir o pdf é:

```
int i = 1;//Sendo n o numero de paginas
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(diretorio);
while(i<=n){
   conteudo+=PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i);
   i++;
}
```

Sei que tem a ver com o encoding, mas não sei como resolver/ o que fazer!
Lembrando que os PDFs não serão gerados por mim.

Comment: Se você copiar e colar o caractere, com o mouse mesmo, como que ele fica? Poderia colar aqui pra gente ver?

Comment: @Math na verdade o exemplo que citei, já foi copiado e colado.

Answer (score 3):

Solução 1: **Fugir ao problema** :)

Editar o Latex e juntar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %% <<<<<< esta linha
\begin{document}
...
```

O PDF gerado já não dá problemas!

Solução 2:

Fazer um posprocessador do texto adulterado vindo do pdf e por
substituições sucessivas restaurar os acentuado -- má ideia...

## Update:

não podendo ser a solução 1: não sei fazer isso decentemente. Normalmente eu uso
ferramentas como o `pdftotext` que aplicado a maus pdf vindos de latex (MPVL)
apresentam o seguinte aspecto: `pdftotext mpvl.pdf`

```
Jo˜ao 
Resumo
fam´ılia esfor¸co
```

e depois de um  `| fix-mpvl`

```
João
Resumo
família esforço
```

No meu caso o `fix-mpvl` faz muitas coisas entre as quais:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use utf8::all;

while(<>){
  s/eˆ/ê/g; s/ˆe/ê/g;
  s/aˆ/â/g; s/ˆa/â/g;
  s/oˆ/ô/g; s/ˆo/ô/g;
  s/e´/é/g; s/´e/é/g;
  s/a´/á/g; s/´a/á/g;
  s/o´/ó/g; s/´o/ó/g;
  s/u´/ú/g; s/´u/ú/g;
  s/a˜/ã/g; s/˜a/ã/g;
  s/o˜/õ/g; s/˜o/õ/g;
  s/n˜/ñ/g; s/˜n/ñ/g;
  s/ı´/í/g; s/´ı/í/g;
  s/c¸/ç/g; s/¸c/ç/g;
  print $_;
}
```

Comment: Serão usados diferentes PDFs e não serei eu que irei cria-los.

Comment: Se você abre o PDF gerado pelo Latex no Acrobat Reader, o texto já aparece errado? Se já estiver errado e você não gera o documento, não tem muito o que você possa fazer. Como o colega João já disse, um posprocessamento é bem difícil e uma má ideia (até porque você não vai saber os tipos de erros que poderão vir, e passa a ter uma enorme responsabilidade que não é sua).

Comment: @LuizVieira não.. o erro no PDF é só depois que extraio o texto dele. Quando abro o PDF no Acrobat ele está normal. O problema creio que seja no encoding do pdf gerado pelo latex.

Comment: Ah, ok, essa é uma informação importante que não estava muito clara na pergunta. :)

Comment: O problema é que sem o `fontenc`, os caracteres complexos são feitos pela sobreposição de dois ou mais caracteres. (em LaTeX, podes pedir para 2 cedilhas com um a com três acentos: o aspecto fica optimo mas são na realidade vários elementos).

Comment: @JJoao Na minha opinião, esse seu último comentário vale a pena ser incluido na resposta. É uma informação muito importante (e interessante - eu não sabia). Se tiver alguma referência oficial que comprove a tal sobreposição, melhor ainda! P.S.: Gostei do acrônimo "MPVL". :)

Comment: @JJoao Esse código, devo testar colocando ele onde?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar usar uma outra biblioteca chamada [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/). A vantagem é que as funcionalidades já estão disponíveis em um `jar`. Você pode testar se funciona no seus arquivos, caso funcione, você pode integrar as classes no seu código fonte.

Você pode baixar diretamente do repositório Maven [aqui](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.pdfbox%7Cpdfbox%7C1.8.9%7Cbundle)

Baixe o jar e execute o seguinte comando no seu arquivo pdf

```
java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar ExtractText [OPTIONS] <inputfile> [Text file]
```

Os parâmetros é você quem tem que pesquisar [aqui](http://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#extractText), visto que eu não tenho detalhes específicos ao seu projeto. Dá uma olhada na opção `-encoding`, talvez esteja ali a resposta para a sua pergunta. Por padrão o LaTeX usa `OT1`, se eu não estou enganado.

Se você conseguir extrair o texto corretamente com o comando, daí você pode adicionar a biblioteca como dependência.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

E usar um [exemplo](http://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/textextraction.html) que usa `TextExtraction` em Java.

Comment: Não entendi o que vc quis dizer com execute o comando no arquivo PDF. Onde executo esse comando?

Comment: @Pacíficão no terminal!